# Pikaday datepicker is showing previous dates in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have one major problem in **pikaday `datepicker`**. Previous dates are not getting disabled and it happens only in IE. It works fine in mozilla and chrome. How to disable it permanently in IE?

Here is my code:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById("datepick"),
    fieldyear: document.getElementById("storeYear"),
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
    maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
    yearRange: [2000, 2020]
});
```

Comment: will you please provide the official link of pikaday datepicker. there must be some solution for this problem on their forum or blog

Comment: https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues.

Comment: I posted my question in their official website but no reply.